# not able to convert char to string with bool char method

Tags: java, string, casting, char, type-conversion

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isVowelTester();
    }

    public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        /*
        This method returns true if ch is a vowel 
        and returns false if ch is any other character. 
        Vowels are the letters a, e, i, o, and u.
         */
        ch = "cod";
        String str = Character.toString(ch);

        if (str.contains("a" + "A" + "e" + "E" + "i" + "I" + "o" + "O" + "u" + "U")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static char isVowelTester() {
        return isVowelTester(System.out.println("Supplied word has vowels: " + isVowel()));
    }
}
```

it gives me a error at ch = "cod"; that it can't be converted. I looked up many examples of how to convert it to a char from a char to string, though it still gives me some type of error pertaining to converting.

Can anyone give me some advice to converting?

Comment: A `String` isn't a `char`.  What single character do you expect Java to turn `"cod"` into?  Also, why are you taking `ch` as a method parameter only to immediately overwrite its value?

Comment: You're checking if a one character string contains "aEeEiIoOuU" - of course, it doesn't.

Comment: I learned String.contains / string.compareto
though not sure I can do it with char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... this is a mess. Firstly look at method `public static char isVowelTester()`. You are calling this method in this method, I mean you are using recursion. You will obtain `StackOverflowError` eventually, because you are only returning the same method in return and there is no other possibility to stop calling `isVowelTester()`, so it will call endlessly (till overflow).
What you can do is only print result, no need to return:

```
public static void isVowelTester() {
    System.out.println("Supplied word has vowels: " + isVowel()));
}
```

But this is not over yet. In method `public static boolean isVowel(char ch)` you have one parameter `char ch`. You **have to** give this method that one parameter. So our previous bit of code must be updated to give this one parameter.

```
public static void isVowelTester() {
    char ch = 'a';
    System.out.println("Supplied word has vowels: " + isVowel(ch)));
}
```

Notice that when assigning char I used '', not "". This is a difference between String and char.
Finally we can go to method `isVowel(char ch)`. You cannot assign `"cod"` to char because this is 3 letters and char, as the name says, is only one character. Also you used quotation marks, what is used in String.
Your if statement is also wrong, because you are not comparing to each character in `contains(...)` parameters, you are comparing to "AaEeIiOoUu", because + sign is used to concatenate strings. You are bassicaly concatenating vowels and after that you are comparing to one character, this will never be true. Better approach is to invert your statement:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    String str = Character.toString(ch);

    if ("AaEeIiOoUu".contains(str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is not finish. You can optimise this, because you are basically returning result of your if. Watch that if your condition is true, you return true, else you return false. So you can just write: `return "AaEeIiOoUu".contains(str)`. That's all you have to do.

Comment: took me a while to understand this but it was ok

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    return "AaEeIiOoUu".contains(Character.toString(ch));
}

ch = 'y'; // possible
ch = "n"; // not possible a string cannot be assigned to a char variable
```

Comment: `"AaEeIiOoUu".indexOf(ch) >= 0` is shorter, and more efficient.

Comment: @AndyTurner I used his methods, as this looks like homework and some information on `Character.toString` was maybe provided. It is also a correction of his use of `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.valueOf(char)` seems to be the most efficient method for converting char to String.

To see all the methods check out the link [6 ways to convert](http://www.java67.com/2015/09/6-ways-to-convert-char-to-string-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isVowelTester();
    }

    public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        /*
         * This method returns true if ch is a vowel and returns false if ch is
         * any other character. Vowels are the letters a, e, i, o, and u.
         */

        String str = new String(ch + "");
        String inMatchString  = "AaEeIiOoUu";

        if (inMatchString.contains(str)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void isVowelTester() {
        System.out.println("Supplied word has vowels: " + isVowel('a'));
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.